# Wordpress paginate through wp_query using foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fetching some users from the DB using wp_user_query. Now I need to add pagination to it but struggling. Below is the code.

Get users:

```
$per_page = 3;
$page_number = 1;
 
$args = array (
  'order'     => 'DESC',
  'orderby'   => 'user_registered',
  'role__in'  => ['editor', 'subscriber', 'author', 'contributor', 'administrator'],
  'fields' => ['ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_login'], 
  'number' =>  $per_page,
  'offset' => ($page_number - 1) * $per_page
);

$query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$members = $query->get_results('ARRAY_A');
```

Template:

```
<?php foreach($this->members as $member): ?>
  <tr data-id="<?php echo $member->ID; ?>">
    <td>
      <?php echo $member->ID; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How would i add a pagination to this? I have tried below code, but that wont work. No errors. But no visual response either.

```
<?php 
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ) );
?>
```